# IBM MQ fetch LGETTIME using Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to fetch Current Depth, Last Puttime & last get time using java  from IBM Mq's to monitor queue performance. I was able to fetch LPUTTIME & current depth using below code. I am using MQMESSAGE browse api. But i am having hard time to fetch the LGETTIME (Last message get time)- last message that was processed out of queue. Because MQMESSAGE browse has nothing like Last get time. Any help regarding this ????

```
public int depthOf(String queueName) throws MQException {
    MQQueue queue = qmgr.accessQueue(queueName, mqOpnOpt, null, null, null);
    int qDpth = queue.getCurrentDepth();

    queue.close();
    //qmgr.disconnect();
    System.out.println("Current Depth of "+ queueName + " is " + qDpth);                
    return qDpth;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private MQQueueManager createQueueManager() throws MQException {
    MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
    MQEnvironment.port = port;
    MQEnvironment.hostname = host;
    MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,
            CMQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

    return new MQQueueManager(manager);
}

/**
 * Returns 1st message put time when it is put in to Queue and not consumed.
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws MQException
 */
public int queueMsgAge() throws MQException {
    MQQueue queue = null;
    MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
    queue = qmgr.accessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_BROWSE
            | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
    MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
    gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST | MQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT;
    queue.get(message, gmo);

    GregorianCalendar cal = message.putDateTime;
    long ageInMillis = new java.util.Date().getTime()
            - cal.getTime().getTime();
    int ageInSeconds = (int) ageInMillis / 1000;
    System.out.println("Put Date & Time: "+ cal.getTime()
            + " Age of Msg in seconds: " + ageInSeconds + " Queue Name "
            + queueName);
    _log.info("Put Date & Time: " + cal.getTime() + " Age of Msg in seconds: "
            + ageInSeconds + " Queue Name " + queueName);
    return ageInSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Using PCF commands you can inquire the Queue status of the queue and as long as you have `MONQ` enabled on the queue manager you can gather `LPUTDATE` `LPUTTIME` `LGETDATE` `LGETTIME` and oldest `MSGAGE` values.  The `MONQ`  information is already tracked so enabling the display of it via `MONQ(HIGH)` will not cause additional CPU usage.

Comment: The code you show is not fetching the LPUTTIME from the QSTATUS it is showing the PUTTIME from the message you just browsed which is not the same thing at all. You cannot obtain status attributes of a queue by browsing a message. See Josh's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

First read JoshMc & Morag's comments above.

Second, you should play around with runmqsc issuing both types of Queue Status commands.  i.e. HANDLE vs QUEUE.  Note: You are interested in the values related to Queue Status Type(QUEUE).

i.e. runmqsc command:

```
DIS QSTATUS(TEST.Q1) TYPE(QUEUE)
```

Third, don't use the MQEnvironment class as it is not thread safe.  Put the connection information in a Hashtable and pass the Hashtable to the MQQueueManager class.

As mentioned in the comments above, you cannot retrieve that information via a regular MQ program.  You need to write a MQ Java program that issues a PCF command to the queue manager's command server.

When creating a PCF request message, the parameters MUST added in a particular order.  It is a bit of a pain but you just get use to it.

Here is a simple MQ Java program that will issue a PCF "Inquire Queue Status" command, get the PCF response messages, loop through the PCF responses and output the information.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQCFC;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQDataException;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.pcf.PCFMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.pcf.PCFMessageAgent;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQListQueueStatus01
 *
 * Description
 *  This java class issues a PCF "inquire queue status" request message for all ("*") queues 
 *  of a remote queue manager. 
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -m MQA1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -q TEST.Q1 -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class MQListQueueStatus01
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat  lOGGER_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

   private Hashtable<String,String> params;
   private Hashtable<String,Object> mqht;
   private String qMgrName;

   public MQListQueueStatus01()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>();
      mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-u") && params.containsKey("-x");
      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ HashTable.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      int port = 1414;
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         qMgrName = (String) params.get("-m");

         try
         {
            port = Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            port = 1414;
         }

         mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, params.get("-c"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, params.get("-h"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(port));
         mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, params.get("-u"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, params.get("-x"));

         // I don't want to see MQ exceptions at the console.
         MQException.log = null;
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   private void doPCF()
   {
      MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
      PCFMessageAgent agent = null;
      PCFMessage   request = null;
      PCFMessage[] responses = null;

      try
      {
         qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
         MQListQueueStatus01.logger("successfully connected to "+ qMgrName);

         agent = new PCFMessageAgent(qMgr);
         MQListQueueStatus01.logger("successfully created agent");

         // https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087880_.htm
         request = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_STATUS);

         /**
          * You can explicitly set a queue name like "TEST.Q1" or
          * use a wild card like "TEST.*"
          */
         request.addParameter (CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");
         request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACF_Q_STATUS_TYPE, CMQCFC.MQIACF_Q_STATUS);

         request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACF_Q_STATUS_ATTRS,
               new int [] { CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME,
                            CMQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH,
                            CMQC.MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT,
                            CMQC.MQIA_OPEN_OUTPUT_COUNT,
                            CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_PUT_DATE,
                            CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_PUT_TIME,
                            CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_GET_DATE,
                            CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_GET_TIME,
                          });

         responses = agent.send(request);

         for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++)
         {
            if ((responses[i]).getCompCode() == CMQC.MQCC_OK)
            {
               String name = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQC.MQCA_Q_NAME);

               int depth = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH);
               int iprocs = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT);
               int oprocs = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_OPEN_OUTPUT_COUNT);

               String lastPutDate = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_PUT_DATE);
               String lastPutTime = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_PUT_TIME);

               String lastGetDate = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_GET_DATE);
               String lastGetTime = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQCACF_LAST_GET_TIME);

               MQListQueueStatus01.logger("Name="+name.trim()+" : depth="+depth + " : iprocs="+iprocs+" : oprocs="+oprocs+" : lastPutDate='"+lastPutDate.trim()+"' : lastPutTime='"+lastPutTime.trim()+"' : lastGetDate='"+lastGetDate.trim()+"' : lastGetTime='"+lastGetTime.trim()+"'");
            }
         }
      }
      catch (MQException e)
      {
         MQListQueueStatus01.logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         MQListQueueStatus01.logger("IOException:" +e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
      catch (MQDataException e)
      {
         MQListQueueStatus01.logger("MQDataException:" +e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (agent != null)
            {
               agent.disconnect();
               MQListQueueStatus01.logger("disconnected from agent");
            }
         }
         catch (MQDataException e)
         {
            MQListQueueStatus01.logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }

         try
         {
            if (qMgr != null)
            {
               qMgr.disconnect();
               MQListQueueStatus01.logger("disconnected from "+ qMgrName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            MQListQueueStatus01.logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple logger method
    * @param data
    */
   public static void logger(String data)
   {
      String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

      // Remove the package info.
      if ( (className != null) && (className.lastIndexOf('.') != -1) )
         className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

      System.out.println(lOGGER_TIMESTAMP.format(new Date())+" "+className+": "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()+": "+data);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MQListQueueStatus01 mqlqs = new MQListQueueStatus01();

      try
      {
         mqlqs.init(args);
         mqlqs.doPCF();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         MQListQueueStatus01.logger("Usage: java MQListQueueStatus01 -m QueueManagerName -h host -p port -c channel -u UserID -x Password");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```