# MQ PCFParameter returning different values for Linux and Windows

Tags: vb.net, ibm-mq

When using  IBM PCF Messages to monitor a queue, getting values of Input Count (MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT), it works perfectly for MQ Servers installed in Windows environment, but not for Linux. Not sure if it is a code or environment issue.

If we connect to a Windows service and perform que query there are more parameters in the response if compared to the Linux.

Same code, different results. Not sure if it is a configuration on the Channel, permissions or any other environment issue. On both MQ Servers the queues are local.

I've tried using IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_STATUS, with no success. Didn't find any workaround to get MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT.

PCFMessages documentation is very limited, so I didn't find anything related to this problem at  MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT documentation: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087810_.htm

Any idea of how to solve this?

```
Public Function GetQtyQConnections(ByVal MQQueueName As String) As Integer

    Dim queueManager As IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager = Nothing
    queueManager = New IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager(AppSettings("MQQueueManagerName"), AppSettings("MQChannelName"), AppSettings("MQConnectionName"))

    Dim oPCFMessageAgent As IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessageAgent = New IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessageAgent

    oPCFMessageAgent.Connect(queueManager)

    Dim pcfMsg As IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage = New IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q)
    pcfMsg.AddParameter(IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, MQQueueName)

    Dim pcfResponse() As IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFMessage = oPCFMessageAgent.Send(pcfMsg)

    Dim pcfResponseLen As Integer = pcfResponse.Length

    Dim inputcount As Integer = -1

    For i As Integer = 0 To pcfResponseLen - 1

        Dim oParams() As IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFParameter = pcfResponse(i).GetParameters

        For Each oParam As IBM.WMQ.PCF.PCFParameter In oParams
            Select Case oParam.Parameter
                Case IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQIA_OPEN_INPUT_COUNT
                    inputcount = Integer.Parse(oParam.GetValue())
            End Select
        Next

    Next

    Return inputcount

End Function
```

On Windows:

```
---------------
2016-QUEUENAME           
20-1
134--3
2027-2018-03-12  
2028-13.59.40
2019-                                                
22-0
2030-                                                
2029-                                                
2124-                                                
96-0
95-0
98--3
2004-2018-03-12  
2005-13.59.40
3-0
2119-                                                                                                                                
61-0
6-0
5-1
184-1
188-0
4-2
7-1
2013-                                                                
34-0
9-0
8-1
272-2
2008-                                                
17-0
15-5000
13-104857600
123--3
16-0
24-0
78-0
18-0
2012-                                                
10-0
190-0
40-80
41-20
43-0
44-0
42-1
46-0
54-999999999
21-999999999
45-1
23-1
128--3
2023-                                                                
29-1
26-0
28-1
12-0
```

On Linux:

```
---------------
2016-QUEUENAME            
20-6
2027-2019-03-11  
2028-17.38.24
2030-                                                
2029-                                                
96-0
95-0
2119-                                                                                                                                
61-1
6-0
5-1
184-1
2013-QUEUEDESCRIPTION
10-0
2017-QUEUEMANAGER                                        
2018-QUEUENAME        
45-1
2024-QUEUEMANAGER
```

Answer (score 1):

From your output I can see that the queue you have looked at on Windows is a local queue. The second parameter you display (20) is MQIA_Q_TYPE and it has a value of (1) MQQT_LOCAL.

The queue you have looked at on Linux however is a remote queue. It's MQIA_Q_TYPE (20) parameter has a value of (6) MQQT_REMOTE.

There are many differences between local queues and remote queues, and their attributes are quite different. Try using runmqsc and display a few local and remote queues to understand the differences. These differences have not occurred because of the different platform, just because of the different queue type.

You say in your question that on both MQ Servers the queues are local, but I'm afraid that is not what your output is showing.

Also, if you want to use the Inquire Queue command, please be sure you know that OpenInputCount and OpenOutputCount are only shown for local queues, not remote queues.

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux and Windows releases of IBM MQ are at the same version level then you should get the same response parameters returned.

Why don't you format your output so that it is readable to the average human?  Nobody will know what you mean by 2016, 2028, etc. (except for me and a few others)

Issues:

1. You did not specify the "Status Type" for the request.  i.e. QUEUE vs HANDLE
2. You did not specify any attributes for the request.

Have a look at MQListQueueStatus01.java code I posted here: [IBM MQ fetch LGETTIME using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602454/ibm-mq-fetch-lgettime-using-java/51619687#51619687)

Finally, why don't you use C# rather than VB?  You could simply use all of the Java/MQ/PCF code that I post since C# is a clone of Java (so to speak).

Comment: The .Net PCF classes are not documented as a supported interface. They may work, they may not...But I certainly would not trust them as being as up-to-date as the Java classes (or doing it by hand in some other language).