# How to get put and get statistics of messages on a local queue in mq?

Tags: ibm-mq

How to get put and get statistics of messages on a local queue in mq?

enabled queue statistics and qmgr statistics

Answer (score 0):

What kind of statistics are you looking for?

A while ago, I posted a fully functioning MQ/Java/PCF program called MQListQueueStatus01.java that performs an Inquire Queue Status on a queue.

You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602454/ibm-mq-fetch-lgettime-using-java/51619687#51619687).

Comment: I want to get information about messages that were put on a queue and that were get off the queue with application name as well.

Comment: It sounds like you want to audit/track the messages, if so, then there is a vendor product called [MQ Auditor](https://capitalware.com/mqa_overview.html) that solves that problem.

Comment: Dont we have any other way instead of going with a vendor product?

Comment: You can play around with amqsmon or amqsact programs to see if they give you what you want or you can write your own program that consumes application activity trace messages if you don't want to purchase a vendor product.  You have to weigh your time vs money. MQ Auditor's website says it cost $299 per queue manager, so if your time is $50 per hour then can you build a fully functioning solution in 6 hours ($299/$50).

Answer (score 0):

### Statistics

To enable statistics which provide overall counts of puts and gets on a local queue in IBM MQ, you need to enable the `STATQ` attribute. You can either enable this on a specific queue only (to avoid collecting statistics for other queues at the same time) thus:-

```
ALTER QLOCAL(q-name) STATQ(ON)
```

or you can enable it for all queues that have the value `STATQ(QMGR)` by using this command:-

```
ALTER QMGR STATQ(ON)
```

Doing either of these will cause statistics messages to be written every `STATINT` interval, to the `SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE`.

### Accounting

To enable accounting which provide application specific counts of puts and gets on a local queue in IBM MQ, you need to enable the `ACCTQ` attribute. You can either enable this on a specific queue only (to avoid collecting accounting for other queues at the same time) thus:-

```
ALTER QLOCAL(q-name) ACCTQ(ON)
```

or you can enable it for all queues that have the value `ACCTQ(QMGR)` by using this command:-

```
ALTER QMGR ACCTQ(ON)
```

Doing either of these will cause statistics messages to be written every `ACCTINT` interval, to the `SYSTEM.ADMIN.ACCOUNTING.QUEUE`.

### Comparing Accounting vs Statistics

The main difference between statistics and accounting is the perspective of the data. Statistics data is collected for the queue as a whole. Accounting data is collected for each individual application. This blog post goes into more details about the comparison between the two.

[Types of Accounting & Statistics](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2020/03/09/accounting-and-statistics/)

### General Information for both

I recommend starting with the queue specific option if you are trying out accounting/statistics collection for the first time, and leaving the queue manager attribute set to `OFF` in the mean time - keep the quantity of data generated a bit lower.

You will then need a program to consume these messages to obtain your numbers of puts and gets.

There are numerous options, but two specifically come to mind for me.

- `amqsmon` sample shipped with IBM MQ
- MQEV program from MQGem (the company I work for) - see [MQEV Webpage](https://www.mqgem.com/mqev.html)

Your may find the following blog post I wrote an interesting read on this subject. It also mentions `RESET QSTATS` and the pros and cons of using that compared to queue statistics.

- [Graphing queue get/put rates](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2022/02/25/graphing-get-put-rates/)

A recently published IBM Support Doc covers using `amqsmon` for exactly this, so you may find that useful reference material as well.

- [Example of amqsmon to display statistics for an IBM MQ Queue](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6966706)

Comment: Is there any way to collect application name and put/get time as well?

Comment: Best way of implementing this is turn on the stats for a local queue and have amqsmon run as a cron job and publish the results to a text file to read from the statistics queue. That way am capturing what ever that comes to the local queue. Let me know if am missing something

Comment: If you want the application name as well then you need to collect accounting data instead of statistics data. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the free sample is the best way. It might be the cheapest way though. A text file is not going to be the easiest way to consume the data later. Have a look into serious products that manage this data - one example in the answer, but of course there are others around if you don't like that one.